# space problems with Internet explorer 6

Tags: internet-explorer

I have this webpage

the OK : http://ldetek.com/a.jpg
the problem : http://ldetek.com/b.jpg

Why is there a HUGE gap of white space for no reason.. only in IE (6)

I know the inline trick.. but it don't work !

coded page : [here](http://ldetek.com/services.php)

---

- if the margin on the #content is remove the problem is fix, but i cannot seem to find solution to get the white space around the whole inside... any idea ?

Comment: You'll need to provide either a link to the live page or at least provide the relevant html and css.  Also, you'll want to tag your question 'html' and 'css'.

Comment: it's done ! like 2 second after the post...

Comment: Also in IE 8 in compatibility mode.

Comment: Oooh!!! Your http://ldetek.com/index.php looks bad on Firefox 3.6.

Comment: still in devlopment.... should not been view !

Comment: Add this on top of your CSS and tell me if this helps:

`* { padding: 0; margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IE 6 the padding-top in #content causes the behavior (I used the [IE Web Development Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) to find it empirically). IE 6 and IE 7 have a problem with the box calculations, and especially the padding. Maybe using margins colud leviate the effect, but I am not sure.

IE 7, IE 6, IE 8 compatibility mode all show the same behavior.

Add a class to all divs except the first and assing margin-top: -50px to it and make sure that this is only applied to IE 6, 7, and 8 if in compatibility view.

Comment: padding top at zero on the content fix the problem... but it like checking if the tire is inflated properly when the car dont start... bizzare !

Comment: **** So any solution to REMPLACE the padding of the #content.... to get a nice white space

Answer (score -1):

no idea about the issue, although removing float from .infoblock fixes it...

Comment: But it alos introduces some other undesired behaviour.